# Delete a text file in java

Tags: java

I have a method to delete a line on a text file which will contain a selected phone number. below is my code.

```
private void DeleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    try {
        String selectedphone = Phone.getText();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        // Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original file
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String line = null;
        // Read from the original file and write to the new
        // unless content matches data to be removed.
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().startsWith(selectedphone)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                pw.println(line);
                pw.flush();

            }
        }
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        file.delete();
        if (!file.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        }

        //rename tempphonebook.txt file back to phonebook.txt
        tempFile.renameTo(file);
        if (tempFile.renameTo(file)) {
            System.out.println("Update succesful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Update failed");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

my 'phonebook.txt' file is as below

```
0787465147|John|Doe|924578654v|Colombo|
0715435786|Jane|Doe|6672475845v|Colombo|
0114745755|Foo|Baz|6454753754v|Kandy|
```

And when I click 'delete' button with a 'selectedphone' as 0787465147 it will create a 'tempphonebook.txt' file as below.

```
0715435786|Jane|Doe|6672475845v|Colombo|
0114745755|Foo|Baz|6454753754v|Kandy|
```

Then the 'phonebook.txt' should be deleted and the 'tempphonebook.txt' should be renamed to 'phonebook.txt'. problem is I'm unable to delete the 'phonebook.txt' file. I get this massage when I click the 'delete' button

```
Could not delete file
Update failed
```

can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you sure the file wasn't deleted?  Your code actually tries twice to delete the file; so the second attempt is sure to fail, either because the file was deleted the first time, or because something prevented it from being deleted.  You need to remove one of the calls to `file.delete()`.

Comment: I checked the folder and the file is still there. also removed the first 'file.delete()'. still getting same massage. I'm beginning to think that something is preventing the file from being deleted.

Comment: Are you running this in Windows?  In my experience, Windows sometimes keeps a file locked for a few milliseconds after you close the `Reader` that's reading from it; so you won't be able to delete it immediately after `br.close()`.  Maybe you could insert a sleep of `20ms` or so before the deletion.

Comment: What do you get for `file.canWrite()`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows 7. I'm new to java. could you please explain how I can do this?

Comment: I would write `try{ Thread.sleep(20); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }`

Comment: Tried that. still getting the same error.

Comment: @Arvind  
 I tried 
        ''if (!file.delete()) {
                System.out.println(file.canWrite());
      } ''
and it returned true

Comment: You could have edited out the file contents completely. They have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Yeah, this was so long ago. I must have been really stupid back then 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to delete the file twice. So if the file is deleted at the first attempt your second call becomes invalid. You need to remove the first one

```
//file.delete(); //not required
if (!file.delete()) {
```

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu:- Check that the file is not open and also you have permission to delete the file.

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu:- Also check that whether some other process is accessing the file? Looks like some process or task is preventing the file to be deleted.

Comment: No, both files were closed when I run the program. I can delete the files manually but I'm not sure how to check if I have permission to delete that file via the program.

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu:- Are you running the program with the administrative access rights?

Comment: of course. I just tried unlocking the file 'honebook.txt' with IOrbit unlocker. It wasn't locked before I execute the program. but while the program is running the file is locked. So I unlocked it before I click the delete button and it was a success. Now the problem is how could it be locked after I close that file and how can I fix this?

Comment: @TharinduKuruppu:- Thats strange but I would agree with David's comment. Please try to insert a sleep after `br.close()`.

Comment: I tried adding 'Thread.sleep(20); ' after 'br.close();' not sure it is the right method but didn't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You try to delete the file twice:

```
    file.delete();
    if (!file.delete()) {
```

remove the first `file.delete();`

Answer (score -2):

Use try-with-resources. This works in most of the cases

And yes remove the extra code for delete and renaming the file.

You just need to use fileName.delete() or fileName.renameTo("name");
once. If the command is successful it will return true.

When you use the command again, it will try to delete the file which does not exists(you have already deleted this).

**See this example 
[Deleting Lines on text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080216/deleting-lines-on-text-file?rq=1)**

It deals with a similar problem.