# Deleting Lines on text file

Tags: java

I Tried this code for deleting certain Lines for my text file. However, when I delete my old file and replace it with new. The file won't be deleted nor be renamed. Can anyone help me with this one ? PS: I tried every method I can find but won't work
I need it for my enrollment system project. Thanks in Advance

```
public static void deleteStudents() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String SY, date;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE SCHOOL YEAR: SY: ");
    SY = console.next();

    int i = 0;

    Scanner print = new Scanner(new FileReader("Students- SY " + SY + " " + ".txt"));
    //display text file
    while(print.hasNextLine())
    {
        String stud= print.nextLine();
        System.out.println(stud);
    }   

    File inputFile = new File("Students- SY " + SY + " " + ".txt");
    File tempFile = new File("Students- SY " + SY + " " + ".txt.bak");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String remove;
    String currentLine;

    System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT's ID NUMBER TO BE DELETED:  ");
    remove = console.next();
    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(remove)) 
        {
            writer.write(String.format("%s%n",currentLine)); 

        }
    }  
    //close reader/writer
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
  //delete file
    if(inputFile.delete())
    {
        tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
```

Comment: You should check the outcome of **all** file operations. Does the call of `tempFile.renameTo(...)` work successfully?

Comment: NO, that's where i got a problem. `tempFile.renameTo(...)` don't work. even the `inputFile.delete())` don't work.

Comment: That is my point. What is the error message or reason. Secondly, your question has too much code, if you knew it was that call that was failing then (1) you should have shown the error messages and (2) you should have removed the unnecessary stuff from the question. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Actually, there is no error at all. But my point is, when I try to run my code, nothing will happen. I want to rename my tempFile to my inputFile. But nothing is happening.

Comment: Removing unnecessary stufff can even often give you the solution... and then even avoid posting the question

Comment: I don't know the Java, but a quick web search of "jave renameto" suggests the method return a boolean indicating successful rename, or otherwise. The search also finds several pages where others have asked why a rename fails. Use the tools available to do your own research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling streams correctly. By the time you try to delete / rename the file, it is still open by Java due to the `FileReader` / `Scanner` held in `print` variable being still open. This will prevent the file from being deleted on Windows.

You need to wrap the reading from file in a `try` block and call `print.close()` in `finally`, or use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Also, don't forget to close the `reader` and `writer` the same way (in `finally` or using *try-with-resources*).

Comment: It works thanks for the Help. Just need to close the `print` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method of the java.nio. package ..
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html

It will show you much more information why the file isn't deleted or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Guys Thanks for all your help. I just solved the problem of my code through your ideas. Here is my final code:

```
public static void deleteStudents() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String SY, date;
    System.out.println("ENTER THE SCHOOL YEAR: SY: ");
    SY = console.next();
    //System.out.println("ENTER DATE TO BE DISPLAYED(MM-DD-YY): ");
    //date = console.next();

    File inputFile = new File("Students- SY " + SY + ".txt");
    File tempFile = new File("Students- SY " + SY + ".txt.bak");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    Scanner print = new Scanner(new FileReader("Students- SY " + SY + ".txt"));
    while(print.hasNextLine())
    {
        String stud = print.nextLine();
        System.out.println(stud);
    }
    print.close(); 

    String remove;
    String currentLine;

    System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT's ID NUMBER TO BE DELETED:  ");
    remove = console.next();

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(!trimmedLine.startsWith(remove)) 
        {
            // if current line not start with lineToRemove then write to file
            writer.write(String.format("%s%n",currentLine)); 

        }
    }  
    writer.close();
    reader.close();

    if(!inputFile.delete())
    {
       tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
        return;
    }
    if(!tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)){
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");
    }
```